# creating a chevron in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm looking at how to create a chevron (not a triangle) in CSS.  Basically create icons that look like `>` or `<`.

On this site: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ at the bottom, there is a chevron.  However, it is pointed down.  I was wondering how I can make it point right, and point left.  I tried playing around with the angles, but I couldn't figure it out since I'm not really sure how these things are created anyway.

As an aside, is this something that should be created in some drawing library like d3, or just use a div?  I'm basically using this chevron to try to separate visually elements on a screen.

Comment: Was there something wrong with my answer?

Comment: @AlexW No there was nothing wrong with it.  I just ended up seeing Fis' anwer first and it made a little more sense to me.  But your answer worked fine.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you figured out a way to add text on top of the chevron?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just do a `rotate(90deg)` on `#chevron` :

```
#chevron {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/29Edw/

Answer (score 27):

```
p:before { content:"\2039"; }
p:after  { content:"\203A"; }
```

A different solution for this particular example (sans rotating and using chevron character codes)

Comment: The simply the best solution.

Answer (score 25):

## Create chevrons using CSS borders

Follow the notes in the example to change the results.

Parameters that can get altered:

1. Rotation.
2. Thickness.
3. Color.
4. Scale.

[image: Example Screenshot]

```css
.chevron {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    height:50px; /*Height should be double border thickness*/
}
.chevron::before,
.chevron::after {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    content:"";
    border:25px solid transparent; /*Adjust chevron size*/
}
/*Change the four instances of 'top' below to rotate chevron*/
/*Use (top/right/bottom/left) where you want the back of the chevron to be*/
.chevron::before {
    top:0;
    border-top-color:#b00; /*Chevron Color*/
}
.chevron::after {
    top:-10px; /*Adjust thickness*/
    border-top-color:#fff; /*Match chevron background colour*/
}
```

```html
<i class="chevron"></i>
```

---

## Create chevrons using CSS SVG

```css
.chevron {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M8 13.1l-8-8 2.1-2.2 5.9 5.9 5.9-5.9 2.1 2.2z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chevron"></div>
```

Comment: This overlaps a triangle with another triangle.  It is not helpful if the background is a multitude of colors. I can't talk about how efficient it is, but because of that, it's not robust.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a simple CSS implementation for a right chevron.  You are creating a border on two sides in the :after pseudo-element and turning it a negative 45 degrees via the rotate() function.

```css
.container:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f00;
  border-right: 1px solid #f00;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: It's as if people forgot about borders!

Answer (score 9):

Here are two other ways to make a chevron with CSS. These do not use transform or rotate so it's compatible with IE8+, but the caveat is that you have to set the color of the chevron AND the color of the background that the chevron is sitting on:

[CSS Chevron - Two Triangles](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinkirchner/DQruj/)

```
.chevron {
    display:inline-block;
    width: .5em;
    height: .8em;
    position:relative;
}
.chevron:before,
.chevron:after {
    display:block;
    content:"";
    width:0;
    height:0em;
    border-style:solid;
    position:absolute;
}
.chevron:before {
    right:0;
    border-width:.4em 0 .4em .4em;
    border-color:transparent transparent transparent red;    
}
.chevron:after {
    left:0;
    border-width:.4em 0 .4em .4em;
    border-color:transparent transparent transparent #fff;    
}
.chevron.skinny {
    width:.4em;
}
.chevron.fat {
    width:.6em;
}
```

---

[CSS Chevron - Three Triangles](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinkirchner/JdSgA/)

```
.chevron {
    display:inline-block;
    background:red;
    width: .55em;
    height: .75em;
    position:relative;
}
.chevron:before,
.chevron:after {
    display:inline-block;
    content:"";
    width:0;
    height:0em;
    border-style:solid;
    position:absolute;
}
.chevron:before {
    left:0;
    border-width:.4em 0 .4em .4em;
    border-color:transparent transparent transparent #fff;    
}
.chevron:after {
    right:0;
    border-width:.4em 0 .4em .4em;
    border-color:#fff transparent;    
}
.chevron.skinny {
    width:.4em;
}
.chevron.fat {
    width:.7em;
}
```

Comment: These are awesome! Trying to get them pointing down, any suggestions?

Comment: Nevermind, if you change the body background then the hack reveals itself and there's no way to make it a true chevron :-(

Answer (score 4):

You can use CSS glyph `&rang; , &lang;` 
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/glyphs/

Answer (score 2):

is such a long code so i made this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8WSB/4/)
basically is made using `:before` and `:after` pseudo selectors

Comment: Is there a way to use this technic, but add text on top of the shape?

Answer (score 2):

I found all these solutions to be a bit more complicated and/or less flexible than what I was looking for (in terms of size and/or thickness), so I wanted to share the code I used. I also included a `Hover` state for use with links.

[Link to Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/f631ewd1/)

**CSS**

```
.chevron a:before {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.1em 0.1em 0 0;  /* Line thickness */
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 5em;     /* Arrow size; Height & Width must remain equal */
  width: 5em;
  left: 0.15em;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);     
  color: #808080;
}

/* Hover State */   
.chevron a:hover:before {
  content: '';
  color: black;
}      

/* Right Arrow */   
.chevron.right a:before {
 left: 0;
 transform: rotate(45deg);    
}

/* Down Arrow */   
.chevron.bottom a:before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  /* To position at top of element, compensate for rotation with margin-top: -2.5em; */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="chevron right">
  <a href="#" style="background-color: white;"></a>
</div>

<div class="chevron bottom">
  <a href="#" style="background-color: white;"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility not mentioned so far is an inline svg, e.g.

```
.breadcrumb::after {
  background-color: #b71c1c;
  width: calc((2/9)*3em);
  height: 3em;
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 2 9'%3E%3Cpath d='M-.1 0L2 4.5L-.1 9Z' fill='%237f0000'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

[image: screen-grab of chevron]

I'm not really a css guy, which may explain why I find this easier to understand and tweak than any of the other suggestions.

[Here](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/)'s a really nice tool for quickly whipping up your svg and escaping it for copy-paste into your css.

This method is also really flexible, because you can draw pretty much anything you want, and e.g. have complete control over the angle at the apex of your chevron which (I think) is not the case with the other methods here.

Another simple example:

```
.profile_menu::before {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  background-color: #b71c1c;
  width: calc((2/10)*3em);
  height: 3em;
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' style='width:100%25; height:100%25' viewBox='0 0 2 10'%3E%3Ccircle cx='8' cy='5' r='8' fill='%237f0000'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

[image: curved border via inline svg]

The biggest drawback I've found so far is having to specify the fill colour in the svg. It would be nice if there's a way around this, but I didn't need it, so didn't spend too much time trying.

Note on compatibility: At time of writing it works in latest firefox (60.0.2), safari (11.1.1), and chrome (67.0.3396.87) on desktop, and chrome/safari on android/ios respectively. That's all I've tested so far.

Comment: I prefer inline svgs for that very reason.
Alternatively, you can link to the .svg OR (even better) a php file with Content-type image/svg+xml that pulls the theme color from the database.

Comment: this is late but if you're using scss you can specify a variable for the color and use that if you need to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Obsidian for your answer. I have converted it into a Sass mixin, so you can easily pass settings through it to generate your arrrows.

```
/* $class outputs the selector, do not place mixin within a rule
   $dir == up, down, left or right,
   $bg == background-color of arrow container 
*/ 

@mixin arrow($class, $size, $weight, $color, $dir, $bg) {
    @if $dir == up {
        $dir : bottom;
    }
    @elseif $dir == down {
        $dir : top;
    }
    @elseif $dir == right {
        $dir : left;
    } 
    @else {
        $dir : right;
    }

   .#{$class} {
       position:relative;
       display:block;
       height: $size * 2;
    }

   .#{$class}:before,
   .#{$class}:after {
       position:absolute;
       display:block;
       content:"";
       /*Size*/
       border:$size solid transparent;
    }

    .#{$class}:before {
        #{$dir}:0;
        /*Arrow Color*/
        border-#{$dir}-color:$color;
    }

   .#{$class}:after {
      /*Thickness*/
      #{$dir}:-$weight;
      border-#{$dir}-color:$bg;
   }
}
```

Example usage:

```
@include arrow(arrow-right, 25px, 5px, #cecece, right, #fff);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to using an existing solution, FontAwesome has this and other glyphs in a icon-font you can leverage in your markup: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/#icon/icon-chevron-down

You would use it like so (after following the instructions to include the required files):

`<i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>`

Answer (score 0):

OK so i needed to be able to ***reuse*** the chevron without repeating an ID. . .so here's what i came up with (thanks Yenn). (i need small chevrons for my app).

it uses a class instead of an ID tag, also uses a cascading class to flip it left. . . instead of doubling up my css code.

```
.chevron {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  height:17px;
  width: 6px;
  margin-left:0px;
  margin-top:0px;
}

.chevron:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
  -webkit-transform: skew(25deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(25deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(25deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(25deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(25deg, 0deg);
}

.chevron:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-25deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-25deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-25deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-25deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(-25deg, 0deg);
}

.rotate180
{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n5Fd8/

Answer (score 0):

CSS3-free, doing it old-school with borders:

```css
.chevron {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.chevron:before,
.chevron:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border: solid black 20px;
}
.chevron.up:before,
.chevron.up:after {
    border-bottom-width: 12px;
    border-top-width: 0;
}
.chevron.up:before,
.chevron.down:after {
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
}
.chevron.up:after {
    border-top-width: 7px;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
.chevron.down:before,
.chevron.down:after {
    border-top-width: 12px;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
}
.chevron.down:before {
    border-bottom-width: 7px;
    border-top-color: transparent;
}
.chevron.left:before,
.chevron.left:after,
.chevron.right:before,
.chevron.right:after {
    display: inline-block;
}
.chevron.left:before,
.chevron.left:after {
    border-right-width: 12px;
    border-left-width: 0;
}
.chevron.left:before,
.chevron.right:after {
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
.chevron.left:after {
    border-left-width: 7px;
    border-right-color: transparent;
}
.chevron.right:before,
.chevron.right:after {
    border-left-width: 12px;
    border-right-width: 0;
}
.chevron.right:before {
    border-right-width: 7px;
    border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<span class="chevron down"></span>
<span class="chevron up"></span>
<span class="chevron right"></span>
<span class="chevron left"></span>
```